# Why the need for 755 permissions for /var/www/? Why not 700 after chown?

Tags: linux, apache, web, permissions

My Apache directory for storing files is /var/www.

If i run,

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

This makes the www-data the owner of the www folder. Since all static/dynamic files will be served by the Apache User, why do i now need to give this folder 755 permissions? It should just work with giving 700 permissions, right? Since with 700 permissions, the owner(www-data) has full permissions for the folder.

Therefore, my question, why do i need to run:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

instead of

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/www
```

**EDIT: I am not facing any error. I am only asking this question for knowledge. I have been suggested to put 755 permission on the /var/www/ folder by a lot of people. Just wanted to know why couldn't i use 700.**

Comment: First just check if "www-data" is indeed your Apache user.  Run this command: echo $(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')

Comment: Yes, this outputs 'www-data'

Comment: This is strange then.  Please put the "700" value back on the folder and can you update your question with the exact error output you get in your error_log file when you try to view your website

Comment: @JohnCrawford: I have no error. I just asked this question for knowledge. I have been suggested to put 755 permissions on the var/www/ folder by a lot of people. Just wanted to know why 700 wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah! I see.  Well a lot of people have been giving you *very* general advice, which in your case is not needed (and actually should not be that open).  Read this: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver if you want a really good setup.  You'll notice that 755 should only be used for "upload" folder and not for your entire folder. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But why would i need the 755 permissions on the "upload" folder. Since the server side script will upload the files and that would be run by www-data which has all the permissions. Also, the server(www-data) has full permission to read the contents on the folder. Why can't i use 700 on the "upload" folder? Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit ambiguous of what I said.  I meant that you should only have 755 if you followed the setup used in that link.  On your setup, 700 will work.  However just so you know, your setup is not regarded as safe.  For example because the entire folder is read/write/execute, I could upload a malicious script on your server AND then execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best layout depends on a few factors. Primarily this is a question of security. Here are a few things to consider:

1) Do you want your web server to be able to write files to your DocumentRoot? Most of the time the answer is no... the exception being things like upload directories. In this case you want something like 755, where the owner/group is *not* the user that Apache is running as.

2) Do you have local user accounts (like developers) that should be able to access the content? If yes, you might want something like 755, root:developers for permissions, with Apache running as "www-data" or "apache", and not in the group (subject to #1 above).

3) Do those devs need to be able to edit the content (do a code push)? In that case, perhaps 775 root:developers is better.

The primary problem with 700 is that it requires the owner to be the user that Apache is running as, and that gives it full permissions to modify any file in the DocumentRoot. This is usually considered a security weakness because generally speaking the web server should not be modifying files in the DocumentRoot apart from pretty specific exceptions.

A common exploitation, is for an attacker to trick your web app into uploading something like a malicious PHP script somewhere into the DocumentRoot, and then visiting that page. One of the countermeasures is to disallow Apache from writing to the DocumentRoot via this sort of filesystem permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I have a doubt. "In this case you want something like 755, where the owner/group is not the user that Apache is running as.". In case of file uploads, which user will attempt to do the file upload? Shouldn't it be www-data?

Comment: Correct- that's a case where Apache does need to own the directory. I realize I worded that poorly. "In this case" refers to the preceding situation, where uploads are *not* involved. Uploads, being the exception, would require something else.